# Can a rust hole in a bath tub be repaired?

Tags: plumbing, bathtub, rust

A few years ago it was a rust "spot" and I thought I did an okay job repairing it with a kit from Rustoleum. It seemed like nail polish, but I wire wheeled the thing clean and whatnot.  Anyway, I don't use this bathroom myself, and fast forward 3 years and the repair not only failed, but this place is structurally unstable.  I think I could easily push my finger through.  Is there any DIY or non-DIY solution, or am I looking at needing a whole new tub?

[image]

Comment: I think if parts of the tub have rusted *all the way through* it would be wise to also remove a bit of ceiling below and inspect the floor, legs, and drainage of the tub.  A bit of a pain to patch and paint but IMO worth it.

Comment: House is on a concrete slab, so minor concern here, just adjacent walls at most.

Comment: Remove the clean-out/overflow cover and if possible get at the overflow tube and get it out of the way, then you can try your patch with access to the backside. Personally, I would replace the tub. My experience with patching rusty steel tubs is that it's a stopgap at best, but if you need some time to set aside money to do that, might as well try the stopgap....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I successfully repaired a hole in my mother-in-laws tub at the drain using an [epoxy putty](https://shop.advanceautoparts.com/p/jb-weld-steelstik-3.5-in.-8267-s/7160037-p?product_channel=local&store=9517&adtype=pla_with_promotion&product_channel=local&store_code=9517&&&&&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAiAiP2tBhBXEiwACslfnrEY9m6saNaCyAH0HTIA-MAhb7aXhX_khtNITvtKzhVwVYHZBzwa5xoCI5sQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) purchased in an autoparts store.

It is made to repair metals and can be formed to fill in the rusted area and then be filed and painted.

You will need to remove the overflow cover to get behind it.  Follow the directions from the manufacturer and be sure to clean away any rust that is around the hole. Push the putty behind the edge of the hole for it to grip there. Then build up enough to fill the hole.  You can smooth it with a damp stick.  Then reinstall the overflow cover to help hold everything in place.

In less than an hour you can file or sand lightly and paint the repair to match.

Comment: I think you're talking about Bondo?  I found this video where he starts with Bondo Glass and then uses two other products along the way that he either didn't show or showed for a few frames.  It shows what can be done in extreme cases:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=64gYUqbZYMc

Comment: Bondo is a brand name. There are equivalents.

Comment: What kind of paint did you use?

Comment: Over the concrete floor it probably doesn't matter, but more generally I would worry about getting a proper seal between my putty job and the flange of the overflow pipe. I think I would probably apply the putty around the back's full perimeter so that my patch could be substantially thicker than the tub. Then use paper to isolate the putty from the flange so I could use flange pressure to shape the back surface of the still uncured putty (I would fear that the uncured epoxy could react with the gasket).

Comment: It's not Bondo...I placed a link in my answer.  This epoxy dries as hard as steel.

Comment: It's glass fiber filled polyester epoxy putty, "Bondo" is polyester epoxy putty - it's a very similar product.

Comment: From the manufacturer: Product Features:
Hand-mixable, steel-reinforced, non-rusting epoxy putty that quickly repairs or rebuilds anything made of metal
Great for patching and repairing automotive and machine parts, plumbing, stripped threads and household repairs
Sets in 3-5 minutes and cures to a dark grey color in 1 hour
When fully cured, SteelStik has a tensile strength of 900 psi and will withstand temperatures of up to 350 degrees F  .    Far from the properties of Bondo.

Comment: I used the JB Weld and it seems to have worked.  I do need to still figure out how to paint it to match since it's basically black.  What kind of paint did you use?  The two part epoxy seems the best, but not sure if it would be too thick since my patch is already flush.

Comment: I used an enamel, tinted to the beige color of the tub. ( I have a good paint store close to me)  I applied it with a brush. Did 3 coats. Sanded with 600 grit after the 1st and second. It took a long time, waiting for the paint to dry and such.  I just made a trip to my mother-in laws every 2 or 3 days.  ( It was ok , She fed me and baked cookies.)